# The ring $R/I$ is a total quotient ring iff $I$ is... what?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

*Conventions.*

1. All my rings are commutative.
2. By a *total quotient ring* (TQR) , I mean a ring whose every regular element is a unit.

Now let $R$ denote a ring and $I$ denote an ideal of $R$. The following fact is well-known:

> **Proposition.** The ring $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal among proper ideals.

I'm wondering if there is a similar theorem for total quotient rings. Therefore, I ask:

> **Original Question.** The ring $R/I$ is a TQR iff $I$ is... what?

*Edit.* I'm also interested in the following, related issue:

> **Second Question.** Is there some weakening of freeness that holds for modules over a TQR?
>
> If so, does this help us answer the previous question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any strong connection with any standard ring theoretic conditions.

To give you an idea of the difficulty in pinning down a condition, consider this. For a von Neumann regular ring, *every* ideal has the property you speak of (that is, $R/I$ is a total quotient ring for every ideal $I$. What standard properties to the ideals have? They are all idempotent, semiprime and flat and divisible (in the sense given by Lam in *Lectures on modules and rings*). Unfortunately, the zero ideal in a nonfield domain also has all of these properties, and yet such a domain is not a total quotient ring.

So, it seems rather hard to see a common thread here beyond the literal translation of your condition:

> $R/I$ is total quotient iff for every $x\in R$ with $(I:x)= I$, there exists a $y$ such that $1-xy\in I$.

Incidentally, I have also seen the rings you describe called "classical rings" and "cohopfian rings" in case that leads to more literature for you.

Comment: I happened on this post by accident a couple of weeks ago. Independen tly, K. Varadarajan (Hopfian and co-Hopfian objects, Publ. Mat. vol 36 (1992), 293-317) and I (Dedekind finite objects in module categories, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 82 (1992), 71-80) noted that a commutative ring $R$ is co-Hopfian as an $R$-module if and only if $R$ is a TQR. Later (Thm 2.3, co-Hopfian modules, arXiv:2201.09961v1) I showed that if $M$ is nonzero finitely generated faithful co-Hopfian module over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$, then $R$ must be semilocal, and its maximal ideals are precisely

Comment: those ideals maximal in Ass(M).  This has relevance to the question above. The ring $R/I$ is a f. g. faithful $R/I$-module whose endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $R/I.$ In this context, $R/I$ is co-Hopfian if and only if $R/I$ is semilocal and its maximal ideals are the only maximal associated primes of $R/I$ (as $R/I$-module). In essence, $I$ must be contained in a finite number of maximal ideals of $R$ and these contain all other prime divisors of $I$.

Comment: @ChrisLeary neat! Thanks for the followup

Comment: @ChrisLeary Huh, do we perhaps have a common connection through [Todd?](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18354/todd-eisworth).

Comment: @rscwhieb - No common connection. Although I did have a brief correspondence with your thesis advisor, Sergio, when submitting a paper to Journal of Algebra and its Applications. The paper didn't work out, but I broke it into two parts and did some revisions. They're both on arXiv, one is the one I mentioned in my comment, with author name F. C. Leary.   Interstingly enough, there is another Chris Leary floating around in mathematics. He's at SUNY Geneseo. If I recall correctly, he does do some work in set theory.

Comment: @ChrisLeary That's probably the one that's an academic sibling with Todd :) it happens though. I met a mathematician named Michael Detlefsen, but not the more famous one.

Comment: @rschweib - They were both students of Andreas Blass, so I would say you are right.

Comment: In the characterization of when $R/I$ is a TQR, I forgot to mention that it holds under the assumption that $R$ is Noetherian. It seems it should hold as long as $I$ has finitely many prime divisors.